# How can I turn on location service on Windows Phone 8.1 RT dynamically?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, geolocation

Now I am having a problem with turning on `Location Service` on `Windows Phone 8.1 RT` app. I used this function to check the status of Location Service on phone (disable or not) and it worked effectively. However, can I do something to turn on `Location Service` in code or navigate my app to turn to `Location Service Page`.
Please help me, thanks a lots!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to turn it on programatically for the user. Using the `ms-settings-location:` uri scheme should open the location settings.

Comment: Nice comment, but can I show it to me specifically?

Comment: Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"))